# How to pass PHP parameter into bat file that is in system32 folder

Tags: php, windows, cmd, command-line-interface

I've created a bat file `php "d:\Dropbox\sync.php"` Then I put this file into <kbd>system32</kbd> folder to be able to call it anywhere in my system. `sync.php` needs an argument.

When I enter some certain folder in explorer and type in cmd `sync arg1` my script says it has no args, but it works if I do in the common way: call it directly without `bat`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `%1` in the <kbd>sync.bat</kbd> file.
Just like this:

```
php "d:\Dropbox\sync.php" %1
```